# Does https make this any more secure?

Tags: security, http, rest, https, asp.net-web-api

I'm reading the API for a web service, and all methods involve sending an HTTP request to

```
https://example.com/api/APIVER/METHOD?apikey=APIKEY&user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD
```

To be clear, both the API key and user password are sent in plain text via the URL. But is this OK because "all HTTPS traffic is encrypted" or not because they're still in plain text or because the URL is somehow different?

If this isn't secure, what is the minimum change the API maintainer needs to do?

Comment: What is the intended usage of this API? Is it a server-to-server call? Or do you intend to make this call from the browser? If you are doing this from the browser, it is NOT secure, but server-to-server is fine.

Comment: It's not intended for the browser, but it can be used by client-side apps (mobile devices, desktop clients, etc)

Comment: Then it isn't secure. Anybody can download the app, monitor the network connection and extract the username / password. An API invoked from client-side apps can only be secured if your users are authenticating with a user specific password.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HTTPS makes this more secure.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS makes this more secure.

You should also send sensitive parameters as POST parameters instead (HTTP BODY) of GET query string ones.  Typically the query string will be logged by Web server logs (server side) in plaintext, so it will be accessible to system administrators that perhaps shouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like POST parameters do work. Unless the API changes, I'll stick with that for my client.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS will encode the URL in each request, so if you are worried about network sniffing then you're OK. HTTPS also adds a nonce value, so you aren't exposed to reply attacks.

It would be possible, depending on infrastructure to insert a fake SSL certificate that's trusted by the user device and route requests through a proxy using that certificate. However this would require admin/root access to the client machines to make such a certificate trusted (barring breach of a normally trusted CA), and once something needs admin access all bets are off anyway.

It's still not a wonderful idea though, I'd be concerned about developers forgetting to configure it for HTTPS. You have an API key, so why not take the password and hash it using the APIKEY as the salt. Now for the API calls the salt is a password equivalent but it would mean that the username and password couldn't be used for logging into elsewhere with those credentials, for example the web site that the API is running off (assuming you let users log in there of course.)

Even better would be to use a shared secret that doesn't go over the wire at all, and use that as the salt.

Comment: I was worried about MitM attacks, so that's good to hear. Your concern about developers forgetting HTTPS is valid, since I just discovered that those calls still work. 

I'm guessing the idea behind the rest of your third paragraph is that if I can keep my APIKEY a secret and use it to salt their password, then I can store it locally? Or will this only help if the API changes to only accept salted passwords?

Comment: I'd change the API to only accept salted passwords. And obviously disable HTTP on your web server.